# How to call appropriate subclass constructor inside base class constructor in MATLAB

Tags: oop, matlab, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to use single inheritance in Matlab, and to write a base class constructor that allows the creation of arrays of objects, including empty arrays, and which is inherited by subclasses. I can't work out how to do it without using some incredibly clunky code. There must be a better way.

In this toy example, my base class is called MyBaseClass, and my subclass is called MySubClass. Each can be constructed with a single numeric argument, or no arguments (in which case NaN is assumed). In the toy example my SubClass is trivial and doesn't extend the behavior of MyBaseClass in any way, but obviously in practice it would do more stuff.

I want to be able to call the constructor of each as follows:

```
obj = MyBaseClass;     % default constructor of 'NaN-like' object
obj = MyBaseClass([]); % create an empty 0x0 array of type MyBaseClass
obj = MyBaseClass(1);  % create a 1x1 array of MyBaseClass with value 1
obj = MyBaseClass([1 2; 3 4]) % create a 2x2 array of MyBaseClass with values 1, 2, 3, 4.
```

And the same four calls for MySubClass.

The solution I have found needs to call `eval(class(obj))` in order to recover the subclass name and construct code in strings to call while in the base class constructor. This seems clunky and bad. (And it's somewhat surprising  to me that it's possible, but it is.) I guess I could duplicate more logic between the `MyBaseClass` and `MySubClass` constructors, but that also seems clunky and bad, and misses the point of inheritance. Is there a better way?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% MyBaseClass.m

classdef MyBaseClass

    properties
        data = NaN        
    end

    methods

        % constructor
        function obj = MyBaseClass(varargin)
            if nargin == 0
                % Handle the no-argument case
                return
            end

            arg = varargin{1};

            % assume arg is a numeric array
            if isempty(arg)
                % Handle the case ClassName([])

                % Can't write this, because of subclasses:
                % obj = MyBaseClass.empty(size(arg));

                obj = eval([class(obj) '.empty(size(arg))']);
                return
            end

            % arg is an array
            % Make obj an array of the correct size by allocating the nth
            % element. Need to recurse for the no-argument case of the
            % relevant class constructor, which might not be this one.

            % Can't write this, because of subclasses
            % obj(numel(arg)) = MyBaseClass;

            obj(numel(arg)) = eval(class(obj));

            % Rest of the constructor - obviously in this toy example,
            % could be simplified.
            wh = ~isnan(arg);
            for i = find(wh(:))'
                obj(i).data = arg(i);
            end
            % And reshape to the size of the original
            obj = reshape(obj, size(arg));
        end

    end

end

% end of MyBaseClass.m
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% MySubClass.m

classdef MySubClass < MyBaseClass

    methods
        function obj = MySubClass(varargin)
            obj = obj@MyBaseClass(varargin{:});
        end
    end 
end

% end of MySubClass.m
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Are you attempting to call a function overridden by base classes from inside the constructor (e.g. before the object is finished constructing)?  In most languages, this is illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is functional and embraces some loose MATLAB typing to achieve what you want. However, getting clean and structured OOP is probably going to require losing some of the functionality you want. At the same time, the best option for avoiding code duplication is templated/generic container classes but these are not supported in MATLAB at this time.

Your code mirrors the MATLAB documentation on [Building Arrays in the Constructor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brd4btr.html)  and relies on MATLAB being a loosely typed language that enabled you to convert an object into an array of objects without problem.  Exploiting this powerful and flexible feature of MATLAB does introduce some organizational issues and may undermine your efforts at clean, object oriented code.
Problems begin because the MyBaseClass constructor is not a true constructor for MyBaseClass.

Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29):

"In object-oriented programming, a constructor (sometimes shortened to ctor) in a class is a special type of subroutine called at the creation of an object. It prepares the new object for use, often accepting parameters which the constructor uses to set any member variables required when the object is first created. It is called a constructor because it constructs the values of data members of the class."

Notice that the MyBaseClass constructor is not constructing values for the object members.  Instead, it is a function that sets the object equal to an array of objects of type MyBaseClass and tries to set *their* data members to some value.  You can see where the obj is destroyed at set to an array here:

```
obj(numel(arg)) = eval(class(obj));
```

This behavior is especially unhelpful  when you derive MySubClass from MyBaseClass because MyBaseClass isn’t supposed to assign a new object to the variable obj----MySubClass has already created the new object in obj and is simply asking MyBaseClass to construct the portion of the existing object in obj that MyBaseClass knows the details for.

Some clarity might be gained by noting that when you enter the constructor for both MyBaseClass and MySubClass the variable obj is already populated with a perfectly good instance of the class.  Good OOP practice would have you keep this original instance, use it in the base class constructor, and only act to populate its members in the constructor----*not* to overwrite the object entirely with something new.
My conclusion would be to not assign obj to be an array inside of MyBaseClass. Instead, I would recommend creating a class MyBaseClassArray that creates an array of MyBaseClass objects.

Unfortunately, you would also need to create a duplicate class MySubClassArray that creates an array of MySubClass objects. Languages like C++ and Java get around  this code duplication issue with templates and generics, respectively but MATLAB does not currently support any form of templates (http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brqzfut-1.html). Without templates there is no good way to avoid code duplication.
You could try and avoid some duplication by creating a generic CreateClassArray function that takes the string name of a class to create and the constructor arguments to use for each object---but now we are coming back to code that looks like your original. The only difference is now we have a clear division between the array class and the individual objects.  The truth is that although MATLAB does not support templates, its flexible classes and typing system  allow you use eval() like you have to change code and overwrite obj at will and create code that acts generically across classes. The cost? Readability, speed, and the uncomfortable feeling you got when you saw  your base class constructing the subclass.

In short, you used MATLAB’s flexibility to overwrite the obj in the constructor with an array to avoid creating a separate container class for MyBaseClass. You then used eval to make up for not having a template feature in MATLAB that would allow you to reuse your array creation code all types. In the end, your solution is functional, reduces code duplication, but does require some unnatural behavior from your classes. It’s just a trade you have to make.